# Подключение GLEW к VisualStudioExpress2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

Всем привет.

Мне нужно подключить библиотеку GLEW (для работы с расширениями OpenGL) к Visual Studio Express 2010.

Скачал архив библиотеки отсюда: http://sourceforge.net/projects/glew/files/glew/1.9.0/glew-1.9.0-… .zip/download

У меня Windows7 x64.

Из архива:

1. Из папки \bin скопировал glew32.dll и glew32mx.dll в \windows\sysWOW64.
2. Из папки \include скопировал папку GL с хедерами glew.h, glxew.h, wglew.h в папку \Visual
       Studio Express 2010\VC\include.
3. Из папки \lib скопировал либы glew32.lib, glew32mx.lib, glew32mxs.lib, glew32.lib в папку 
       \Visual Studio Express 2010\VC\lib.
4. Создал проект - консольное приложение Win32. В свойствах проекта>>свойства  конфигурации>>компоновщик>>ввод в дополнительных зависимостях прописал подцеплять glew32.lib, glew32mx.lib, glew32mxs.lib, glew32.lib, opengl32.lib.
5. Написал пару строк просто для проверки, как библиотека работает.

.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <glew.h>

int main() {
    GLenum res = glewInit();
        return 0;
}
```

Построилось всё без проблем, а вот при запуске выдаёт окошко с ошибкой приложения:
"Ошибка при запуске приложения (0xc0000007b). Для выхода из приложения нажмите кнопку "ОК".
Я уже второй день не найду, в чём причина. Подключал glut - всё идёт без проблем. А с glew такая вот засада. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что тут может быть?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй скомпилировать в режиме Release вместо Debug
http://www.cyberforum.ru/visual-cpp/thread845225.html

Если это сработает, то можно в Debug исправить опцию на Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library : Multi-threaded DLL (/MD) . После этого у меня заработал и Debug режим. Только сперва удали созданные папки Debug в папке проекта и построй приложения заново уже с новыми настройками.